# White line appears at end of gradient filled div at specific browser widths

Tags: html, css, background-image, linear-gradients

I have a div with id `#gradient_div` with a `background-image` set to `linear-gradient`. I'm getting a gap between the end of the linear-gradient and the end of the div `#gradient_div` only at certain browser window widths. As I stretch and shrink the browser window this white line disappears and reappears.

[image]

It seems like it **has something to do with the margin:**

- When I have the margin set to `margin: 0 1%;`, the while line appears
  at specific window widths.

  At **1%** the white line appears whenever the window width ends in
  the range of **68-92** *ex: 4**68**px-4**92**px, 5**68**px-5**92**px,
  6**68**px-6**92**px, etc.*

  For other margin left and right percentages, the line appears at these page
  widths:

  - 2% : page widths ending in the range 92-_04 and 42-54
  - 3% : page widths ending in the range 34-41, 67-74, and 00-08
  - 30%: page widths ending in 5 or 8

There is **NO white line problem** when I just set the background to a color as opposed to a gradient, ex `background: blue;` or when I set the `background-image` to an image; **UPDATE** It also doesn't happen when margin is set in px.

Suggestions to fix this are welcome but I'm mostly interested in understanding **why** this line is happening. What's causing this?

```css
    #gradient_div{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 126, 255, 0.86) , rgb(152, 4, 228));
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 1%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div id="gradient_div"></div>
```

Comment: Did you try testing in a different browser like Firefox? Works fine even in Edge. This seems to be an issue with Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would increase the size of background a little to avoid this:

```css
#gradient_div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 126, 255, 0.86), rgb(152, 4, 228));
  background-size: 101% 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 1%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="gradient_div"></div>
```

You can also try to add only `1px` it will be probably less than `1%`

```css
#gradient_div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 126, 255, 0.86), rgb(152, 4, 228));
  background-size: calc(100% + 1px) 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 1%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="gradient_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that's a really great workaround. Still wondering why it happens in the first place. But really smart idea, I didn't know about that property.

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss it's for sure a rounding issue. By default the size is 100% so probably at certain point the 100% is rounded at less than the 100% .. if we increase the size we can cover this (Added another method)

Comment: Oh that's actually what I was wondering, thanks for the explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @TemaniAfif Excellent workaround however can we be sure it's a rounding issue? Changing the background-size property fixes the problem even if it's set to some arbitrary value (i.e. 10%, 50%, etc.) as long as it's NOT 100% fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/73rsLpth/

Comment: @jjrabbit don't forget that in this case the background is from top to bottom and you also have the repeat so changing to any size will work because the pattern is the same, try to use another gradient (to right or to left) and you cannot change to any size without messing the gradient ... and I am sure but not at 100%. This is the logical explanation I found, it's probably something else at the end, difficult to know

Comment: @jjrabbit by the way, no need to delete your question, it can be useful as it may attract search result and poeple may find this question by yours ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ah okay that's why it works. Yea not sure, I feel like this is a Chrome bug since it renders fine in other browsers. As for deleting the question I thought duplicates are supposed to be removed. Oops I'll leave it up next time, thanks.

Comment: @TemaniAfif By the way, oddly enough setting the background-repeat property to no-repeat fixes that guys problem: https://jsfiddle.net/yx0ct5u4/

Comment: @jjrabbit probably the no-repeat will make the algorithm behave differently and the bug will disappear.