# How to style a responsive chessboard with 1px transparent gaps?

Tags: css, flexbox, transparent, linear-gradients

I have built this:

```
.board {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-content: stretch;
    flex: 1 1 0;

    .cell {
     flex: 1 1 0;
     background: padding-box linear-gradient(280deg, red 0%, dodgerblue 0%, blue 100%);
     border-top: 1px solid transparent;
     border-left: 1px solid transparent;

     &:hover {
       background: padding-box red;
     }

     &::after {
       display: block;
       content: "";
       padding-top: 100%;
     }

     &:first-child {
       border-left: none;
     }
    }

    &:first-child .cell {
       border-top: none;
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b58tfqzw/2/

It works fine in firefox, but in Chrome and Edge it shows a 2 pixel gap instead of a 1 pixel gap and it looks terrible.

Why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: probably the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54951221/8620333 ?

Comment: Nope, the problem still exists. :-(

Comment: I believe this is a bug in Google Chrome. Please read the comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208961/why-does-2px-border-render-taller-than-2px-height-in-firefox-and-chrome) for more information.